# Pololu Pushbutton Power Switch

Tags: switches, pololu

I am replacing my auxiliary light switch of my car.

on the switch assembly, it has a positive, negative, and ground.
I am replacing it with a pololu pushbutton power switch with an oem switch that is a momentary type.

Here is the switch: http://www.pololu.com/product/750/pictures

Positive to Vin
Negative to Vout
There are 4 grounds on this circuit board, so which one is the correct one to connect to the right ground?

Or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you link to shows a picture of the breakout board.  The lighter green patches are the copper traces connecting the silver contact pads.  You can see that a large trace connects all four Gnd pins together, so you can use any one of them.  The same goes for Vin and Vout: each pair of pins is connected together.